# mysqldump from inside php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to dump the DB by using mysqldump command from inside a simple php script but the output file is null, is there something wrong in this script?

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'best.hostname.com';
$dbuser = 'best';
$dbpass = 'pass4best';
$dbname = 'best';

exec('mysqldump --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --pass=$dbpass $dbname > best.sql');

?>
```

Comment: The output file seems to contain some values but not what is intended, it contains:"Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help"

Comment: You need double quotes around your command string otherwise you will not get any variable interpolation. You are passing literal variable names to the command. Voting to close as typographical error. You also may want to consider escaping the variable arguments you are passing to the shell as a matter of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the command should be

`exec('mysqldump --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --pass=$dbpass --databases $dbname > best.sql');`

Comment: Anyone of these syntax gives the same value: exec('mysqldump --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --pass=$dbpass --databases=$dbname > bestlimo.sql');
exec('mysqldump --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --pass=$dbpass --all-databases=$dbname > bestlimo.sql');

Comment: remove the `=` sign after databases

Comment: actually im not sure you should have any `=` signs in the command, just spaces

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **exec()** is not working but **shell_exec()** worked !
The working code is:

```
shell_exec( "mysqldump --allow-keywords --opt -h$dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname | gzip> $backup_file");
```

Thanks